# Problems using String resources (strings.xml) with parameters

Tags: android, android-resources, android-lint

I'm using strings with parameters, like this:

```
<string name="share_1">My Android device has reached %1$s points in the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%2$s</string>

String s = getString(R.string.share_1, result.getText().toString(), activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Lint is giving me this error: "format string is not a valid format string so it should not be passed to string.format"

I'm using Last version of Android Studio, last version of Gradle and

```
compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only lint error. You can disable lint error in gradle

```
 lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
  }
```

And you should use ContextCompat to get string and concat it.

Comment: ContextCompat is no longer to be used to concat strings. I use the regular `getString(resource, params)`

Comment: Plus, this is not a valid solution as you are only hiding lint errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your string contains parameters that `String.format()` will try to search and replace. Your app name is always the same and that URL param does not need to be replaced. Take out the URL and format it separately, then concat both:

**XML:**

```
<string name="share_1">My Android device has reached %1$s points in the app:</string>
```

**Java:**

```
String myAppUrl = String.format("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%s", activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

String score = getString(R.string.share_1, result.getText().toString())

String toBeDisplayed = String.format("%s %s", score, myAppUrl);
```